# ConnectX-5 DPDK performance degradation when enabling jumbo, scatter and multi segs

Tags: nvidia, dpdk, nic, mellanox

I’m using a `ConnectX-5` nic.
I have a `DPDK` application on which I want to support `jumbo packets`.
To do that I add rx offload capabilities: `DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_JUMBO_FRAME`, `DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_SCATTER`
And tx offload capabilities: `DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS`
I also make the `max_rx_pkt_len` higher so it will accept jumbo packets (9k).
I’ve noticed that adding these offload capabilities + increasing the `max_rx_pkt_len` harms performance.
For example, without those offload flags, I can redirect `80Gbps` packets of size 512 without any drop.
Using those flags reduce to `~55Gbps` without losses.
I’m using `DPDK 19.11.6`.
Currently in this test I do not send jumbo packets. I just want to understand how it affects the average packet size.

Is this expected? Using those offload flags should degrade performance?
Thanks

-- Edit --

Port configuration:

```
const struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = {
        .rxmode = {
                .split_hdr_size = 0,
                .offloads = DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_JUMBO_FRAME | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_SCATTER,
                .max_rx_pkt_len = 9614;
        },
        .txmode = {
                .mq_mode = ETH_MQ_TX_NONE,
                .offloads = DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS
        },
        .intr_conf.lsc = 0
};
```

--- Further information --

```
# lspci | grep Mellanox
37:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]
37:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]

# lspci -vv -s 37:00.0 | grep "Part number" -A 3
            [PN] Part number: P23842-001
            [EC] Engineering changes: A6
            [SN] Serial number: IL201202BS
            [V0] Vendor specific: PCIe EDR x16 25W
```

Comment: can you please share the NIC arguments enabled if any? Can you also please share if the configuration is enabled for port and queue while setting and mbuf_fast_free is disabled?

Comment: @VipinVarghese thanks. I shared the above port configuration. Is that what you meant? This configuration is set per port. I do not set `mbuf_fast_free` because I might have multi cores. Does it answer your questions? Please let me know if it does not. Thanks

Comment: thanks will take a look at the same, please update NIC, firmware and arguemnts used if any too,

Comment: @VipinVarghese I'm not sure about how to get those stuff. I saw this for the firmware 
 - please see updated question. Can you let me know how to get all the rest? Thanks

Comment: please find the command `mst start; ofed_info -s; ibv_devinfo; ethtool -i <nic>`

Comment: with mlx5 driver I need pass `mprq_en=1,rxqs_min_mprq=1,mprq_log_stride_num=9,txq_inline_mpw=128` to enable JUMBO frame rx-tx. Hence I have requested you to share the details to better understand how to reproduce the error. please let me know

Comment: Thanks. I'm still try to figure out if I have `mst` application on my device. I currently cannot find it.

Comment: I have updated with the answer show casing enabling jumbo does not affect line rate or throughput

Comment: Thank you. I will try to learn the answer

Comment: it is clearly pointed out the initial assumption enabling jumbo degrades performance is incorrect. Please close the question by accepting the answer to help others in understanding and finding the right answer.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I cannot accept because I couldn't test it yet. I hope I'll be able to soon. :/

Comment: thanks for the reply `that you have not test`. please test asap and accept as it will help others

Answer (score 1):

With DPDK 21.11.0 LTS using MLX5, I am able to send an receive 8000B at line rate using single RX queue with 1 CPU core. While for smaller packet size like 64B, 128B, 256B and 512B (with JUMBO Frame support enabled) I am reaching line rate with right configuration. Hence highly recommend to use dpdk 21.11 or use LTS drop as it contains fixes and updates of MLX5 NIC as it could be the DPDK 19.11.6 could have potential fixes missing (there are rework on mprq and vector code in mlx5).

[image]

Packet Throughput with 1 RX and 1 TX queue:
[image]

Note: Using the following args I am only able RX and TX jumbo frames with MLX5 supported NIC `mprq_en=1,rxqs_min_mprq=1,mprq_log_stride_num=9,txq_inline_mpw=128`

Steps to follow:

1. Download dpdk using `wget http://fast.dpdk.org/rel/dpdk-21.11.tar.xz`
2. build dpdk using `tar xvf dpdk-21.11.tar.xz; meson build, ninja -C build install; ldconfig`
3. Modify DPDK example code like l2fwd to support JUMBO frames (refer code below)
4. enable MTU of minimum of **9000B** on NIC (In case of MLX NIC, since the PMD does not own the nic and is used as representations, change MTU on netlink kernel interface with `ipconfig` or `ip` command also).
5. use ixia, spirent, packeth, ostaniato, xiena or dpdk-pktgen to send JUMBO frame.

l2fwd modification to support JUMBO in DPDK 21.11.0:

```
 95 static struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = {
 96         .rxmode = {
 97         .max_lro_pkt_size = 9000,
 98         .split_hdr_size = 0,
 99         },
100         .txmode = {
101         .mq_mode = ETH_MQ_TX_NONE,
102         .offloads = (DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM |
103                      DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS),
104         },
105 };
```

Comment: I have the same problem than OP on 23.03